# PHP: Is there any way to hide warning for a specified deprecated class in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, format, warnings, settings

[Hide deprecated warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BICFw.png)

Does anyone know if there is any way to hide warning for a specified deprecated class (not all warning) in VS Code?

I am using VS Code Version: 1.55.2 (Universal) and PHP IntelliSense v2.3.14

Answer (score 0):

From (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49):

> Disable these strike throughs by setting "editor.showDeprecated":
> false

See also here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511

> The word 'super' then gets striked through and hovering over seems to
> say it is deprecated for typescript, but this is not a typescript
> file. It does not affect the code but is confusing many people.
> Working around it by disabling the "Editor: Show Deprecated" setting,
> but would prefer to be able to enable that setting. This has only been
> happening since the VS Code update on August 10, 2020 (yesterday).